# Configuring Webpack to required folder structure for build files

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a ReactJS application, that was built using Webpack. So, in my ***webpack.config.js***, I have return the required code to take a build, and everything builds into a '*build*' file, in my project folder.

This is the current file structure:

```
Project
  | -- build
     | -- index.html
     | -- bundle.js
     | -- background.png
     | -- avatar.png
```

However, I want my build files to take a separate structure, as shown below:

```
Project
      | -- build
         | -- templates
              | -- index.html
         | -- static
              | -- js
                    | -- bundle.js
              | -- images
                    | -- background.png
                    | -- avatar.png
```

My ***webpack.config.js*** is provided below. I tried tweaking it, and the structure was obtained, but the images failed to load. The HTML and JS worked without any issues, but the images just didn't load. Shown below is the unaltered code, which builds all the files into a single folder.

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
var path = require('path');

const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./src/index.html",
  filename: "index.html"
});

module.exports = {
  entry: ["@babel/polyfill", './src/index.js'],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
  },
  devtool: "#eval-source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        include: /(src[\/\\]js)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: /(src[\/\\]jsx)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.json?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css?$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'raw-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss?$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'raw-loader', 'sass-loader', 'import-glob']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|ico|gif)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?limit=30000&name=[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [htmlWebpackPlugin]
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `webpack.config.js`, set your filename to `static/js/bundle.js`. This will output your bundle in a newly created `build/static/js` directory:

```js
module.exports = {
// ...
  output: {
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
  },
// ...
}
```

Then set the [`outputPath` property of `file-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#outputpath) to `static/images/`

```js
      // ...
      {
        test: /\.(png|ico|gif)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'static/images',
        }
      }
      // ...
```

Comment: That solves one thing. The images and the js are in correct path. But, as specified in the original post, I would also like to add the **index.html** in a "_templates_" folder, inside the build folder

Comment: I tried specifying the path for html file as: filename: _"templates/index.html"_ , but this failed to load the images in browser.

Comment: Ok, can you update your question to include on what wrong locations your browser is trying to find the images?

Comment: The browser is trying to retrieve the images in this address: "_**Project/build/templates/static/images/background.png**_". Whereas, the images are actually in "_Project/build/static/images/background.png_"

Comment: maybe you need to setup `publicPath` to the `file-loader` options ?https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader

Comment: @LucianoSemerini, I added ***publicPath: 'static'*** to "_test: /\.(png|ico|gif)?$/_", still no luck.

Comment: What happens if you don't put it there (in the plugin), but in Webpacks `output.publicPath`, with the value `/static/` ? See https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpublicpath

Comment: With the inputs from you guys, and a little improv, I managed to fix it. I modified the **publicPath** as "***publicPath: '../static/images'***" , that solved everything.